# Target multiple images in for loop visual c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Hello I'm new to visual c# .net. 
I am currently working on a WPF Project. In the xaml designer I created multiple images named image1, image2, image3...etc.

Now depending of the size of a List I would like to change the source of the images.
For example, usually I would do that for each image object created:

```
image1.source = myList[0].ImageSource;
image2.source = myList[1].ImageSource;
image3.source = myList[2].ImageSource;
...
```

But I am looking for something like:

```
int numberOfItemsInList = myList.Count();

for (int i=0;i < numberOfItemsInList; i++){
image[i+1].Source = myList[i].ImageSource;
}
```

I hope you understand what I mean. Is that even possible?

Comment: what is type *image* in the code `image[i+1]`?

Comment: well if my first image is named "image1" and i would be 0, than this would not work, therefore I wrote i+1 for explanation.

Comment: No.... using image[x] is referring to the *index* of the item in the array named image (which I think you don't have?), you cannot use it to get different named variables such as image1, image2, etc. Read it as image *at* index 1, 2, etc.

Comment: I know that I cannot use image[x] to get the different named variables, that's why I was asking. But the answer given by AlexD works fine for me. Thank you all.

Comment: Take a look at the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) article on MSDN. Then create an appropriate ItemsControl in your application that displays a collection of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create `images` array first, and then do the loop:

```
var images = new Image[] {image1, image2, image3};
for (int i=0;i < images.Length; i++){
    image[i].Source = myList[i].ImageSource;
}
```

Comment: This answer works for me. Thank you very much. I didn't know that I can do this.